# Python 'For' Loops: How to store the output in a Dictionary

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the website named below, my code scrapes the names of NGOs and the related information data off of it, but it doesnt store them together in one Dict. Individually, my for loops are getting the data, but they don't together. So, my Dict ends up storing either the last value of NGO_name or data stored in ITEM variable below.

And when I run the two 'for' loops separately, keeping the other loop commented out, I get,

```
{'NGO_Name': 'INDIA INCLUSION FOUNDATION', 'Pancard': 'AABTI3598J'}
```

Together, they dont work. How should I achieve this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Safari()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
driver.get("site")

it_data = {}


while True:
        for elem_li in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("exempted-detail"):

            for item in elem_li.find_elements_by_tag_name("li"):
                it_data[item.find_element_by_tag_name('strong').text] = item.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text



        for elem, pan_li in zip(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fc-blue fquph"),driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pan-id")):

                    it_data["NGO_Name"] = elem.text.replace(pan_li.text, '')
                    it_data["Pancard"] = pan_li.text

        print (it_data)

        try:
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_d6877ff2_42a8_4804_8802_6d49230dae8a_ctl00_imgbtnNext"))).click()
            wait.until(EC.staleness_of(elem))
        except Exception as e:
             print(e) 

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Unrelated,  but - how does the `while` loop ever ends? Also, check the code formatting in the question, there is a statement with just `it_data`, in the first inner for loop; what's its purpose?

Comment: You're right that was a stray it_data, Also, the while loop only ends when the pages on the site run out.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop scrapes each value one at a time. Right now you are overwriting the values, not appending. Try appending each scraped key/data pair into arrays and once the for loop has completed, zip those two arrays into a dict. Then you can append the 'NGO_Name' and 'Pancard' to the dict you created.

You also don't need while True, once the for loop runs out it will exit itself.

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
driver.get("SITE")

for elem_li in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("exempted-detail"):
    keys = []
    values = []
    for item in elem_li.find_elements_by_tag_name("li"):
        exempt_keys = item.find_element_by_tag_name('strong').text
        exempt_values = item.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text

        keys.append(exempt_keys)
        values.append(exempt_values)

it_data = dict(zip(keys, values))

for elem, pan_li in zip(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fc-blue fquph"),
                        driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pan-id")):
    it_data["NGO_Name"] = elem.text.replace(pan_li.text, '')
    it_data["Pancard"] = pan_li.text

print(it_data)

try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.ID, "ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_d6877ff2_42a8_4804_8802_6d49230dae8a_ctl00_imgbtnNext"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(elem))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: this code also gets just the last value on the page, but when I run the two loops together, it doesnt print and loop through all the names.

Comment: I also ran the code and got the expected output you stated above. You should just need to run this entire script without breaking it up or commenting anything out.